# Autofill of OTP on WebApp and Android App

Tags: android, web-applications

Wanted to know if we can have the OTP auto-filled for WebApp and Android App using a single message, rather than trigerring two separate templates based on the device the user is using?

Answer (score 1):

There are different individual formats for android and webapp for auto-filling otp, but you can combine both of them to work on both android and web
Ex:
<#> 584363 is the OTP for creating an account on TestApp
@web-otp.glitch.me #123457
kiO0Tyffsb

for testing on webapp you can use: https://web-otp.glitch.me/